# Как получить девайс мыши/клавиатуры из хука?

Tags: winapi, delphi, мышь

Всем привет)

Собственно вопрос в сабже.

Подробнее: к компу подключено несколько (2+) мышей и клавиатур. Задача в том, чтобы на каждое движение/нажатие иметь какой-то уникальный идентификатор устройства, т.е. иметь возможность узнать, что именно подало сигнал. Хук - кажущийся самым очевидным способ, не принципиально, если есть другой - тоже хорошо.

Предпочтительно делфи, винапишные примеры на чем угодно. Реализуемо ли?

Comment: имхо, драйвер у обеих мышей один и не делает разделения на девайсы. если вот драйвер написать..., но это не про дельфи и не винапи.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov вообще есть как минимум [multipoint mouse sdk](http://www.microsoft.com/multipoint/mouse-sdk/) (без драйверов) и ~драйвер [CPNMouse](http://cpnmouse.sourceforge.net/), которые различают устройства, я собственно потому и заинтересовался, как это можно повторить, а ставить дополнительный софт и ковырять опенсорс желания нет.

Comment: рад был ошибиться )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать зарегистрировать устройства с помощью `RegisterRawInputDevices` и отслеживать сообщения `WM_INPUT`. Пример реализации подобного подхода для различения клавиатур здесь: [Using Raw Input from C# to handle multiple keyboards](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard).

Comment: Круто, благодарю) 

В принципе этого достаточно, дальше справлюсь.